# Как в java проверить строку на наличие определенных символов?

Tags: java

Есть строка "REMBO IUI Z&&" ,как мне проверить на наличие символов &&

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В классе String определен метод `int indexOf(String sub)`

```
String s = "dkdbd&&dgs", sub = "&&";
if (s.indexOf(sub) != -1)
    //элемент есть
else
   //подстроки нет
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String s = "REMBO IUI Z&&";
if (s.contains("&&")) {
  // действие
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public static boolean contains(String str, String substr){
    return str.contains(substr);
}

contains("REMBO IUI Z&&", "&&");
```

Или регуляркой:

```
public static boolean contains(String pattern, String content) {
    return content.matches(pattern);
}

contains("(.*)&&(.*)", "REMBO IUI Z&&")
```

Answer (score 1):

с помощью `contains` например.
[документация](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Answer (score 0):

Для тестировщика автоматизатора будет полезен вот такой вариант решения:

```
@Test
    public void verifyWelcomeTextIsDisplayedOnMainPage() {
       String expectedWelcomeText = "&&"; //символы или текст, который нужно найти
       WebElement elementWelcomeText = DriverProvider.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'content animation-screen')]")); //указываем на элемент со страницы, в котором находится нужная нам строка
       String actualWelcomeText = elementWelcomeText.getText();
       Assert.assertEquals(actualWelcomeText.contains(actualWelcomeText), expectedWelcomeText.contains(expectedWelcomeText), "There is no symbols &&");
    }
```