# Как проверить строку на наличие символа "?

Tags: java, char

1. Как добавить в строку символ " ?
2. Как проверить строку на наличие символа " ?

   ```
   System.out.println("text "\")
   ```

Comment: Учебники по джаве читали?

Comment: Нет, от делать нечего спрашиваю. Как добавить уже догадался, а вот как проверить, понятия не имею

Comment: Если вам нечего делать, почитайте учебники :)

Comment: Действительно надо перечитать) Не вспомнил о экранировании)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как в java проверить строку на наличие определенных символов?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/583791/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-java-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Экранировать надо обратным слешем `\"`

**Upd**В вашей строке обратный слеш после кавычек, а должен быть перед.